# Azure AD token 5 minutes behind

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, token

I am using RS256 algorithm to generate Azure AD token.

When I decode the token in https://jwt.io/ The issued at is 5 minutes behind the time of request.

Requested time: 9:00:00 PM IST.

Issued at: 8:55:00 PM IST.

Little strange but why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking at the the time converter and seeing this difference?

Comment: Yes, I took the UNIX time stamp of "Iat" and converted it to IST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "Clock Skew" and the official reason is

> The need of the clock skew is to avoid situations where the client clock and the token issuing service clock are not exactly in sync. However, we plan to make it a configurable value and is in our backlog.

You can read more about it e.g. [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/512)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation, but that's by design. To make sure that when some systems have some minor offsets of times, then tocen is still good for acceesing your app/env

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).